# UIWebview is off loading url

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiwebview, nsstring

so I have an odd approach for loading bookmarks in a UIWebView in a browser app I am making.  For the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the Bookmarks UITableView, I have this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *lString = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[lString setValue:[bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"loString"];
```

and then I have a modal for the selected object in the UITableView to another view controller which loads a UIWebView based on this code.  So the problem is that the first time I click the table view object, the UIWebview is blank, then the second time it shows the URL that I clicked the first time.  PLEASE HELP!
Thanks,
Michael

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *lString = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
loadString = [lString valueForKey:@"loString"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:loadString];
NSURLRequest *togo = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest: togo];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The -loadRequest method is asynchronous, meaning that it starts the load in another thread while your main thread's execution continues.

So the first time it's called, it shows a blank screen (because the first request is still running in another thread). The second time, because the first request has now finished, it shows that (while the second request runs in another thread). And so on.

To refresh the screen with the URL contents as soon as they load, you need to implement the -webViewDidFinishLoad method of your UIWebViewDelegate. In that method, you know the URL has finished loading, so if you refresh the web view there it should show the contents.

Comment: Thanks, and how would I do that?

Comment: Hi, I tried your tip, but I need a way of it reloading the page only once.

Comment: You need to assign an object as the delegate of your UIWebView object. This delegate object needs to be retained by your application or another non-view object so it is not garbage collected. It needs to be declared as conforming to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol.

The only method you should need to implement is the `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` method, which will pass as an argument a pointer to your webView object.

In that method, you should only need to call:

`[webView setNeedsDisplay];`

to alert the system that the webView needs to be redrawn.